# automorphism of $G-$set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to solve the following problem:

> Let $H<G$ an automorphism of $G-$set of $G/H$ is an equivariant bijection from the set to itself. The automorphism of $G/H$ from a group under composition, and we denote this group by $Aut_G(G/H)$.
>
> Show that $Aut_G(G/H)$ is isomorphic to $N_G(H)/H$.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: in fact i didn't find the appllication  that we should prove is bijective. Please help me. I will be gratfull if you do so. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note that any $\phi\in \mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$ satisfies $\phi(xH)=x\phi(H)$. Now, suppose that $\phi(H)=gH$, and write $\phi=\phi_g$ accordingly. Now, you should prove the following:

1. $\phi_g\in \mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$ if and only if $g\in N_G(H)$.
2. The map $\Phi:N_G(H)\to \mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$, $g\mapsto\phi_g$ is a surjective homomorphism.
3. $\ker\Phi=H$.